# Filestreaming in SQL Server 2012 creates an empty file instead of using the existing file

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I experience a strange problem at a customer's server. Unfortunately it is not possible to debug in their environment and I couldn't recreate the problem at our server when sending the same message. Basically they have two programs installed: 1) A windows service that checks an email account for messages, and 2) a webservice that is called by windows service when a new message has been received.

The windows service uses the code below (method SaveToFileTable) to save the file in the SQL Server using filestreaming. After saving the file, it calls the webservice with the primary key for the file and the webservice reads the content of the file and processes it.

**The Problem**

But what happens is, when I check the file catalog, there is actually 2 files created. First the correct file with content in it and then an empty file. The market server reads the empty file and throws an exception.

**Questions**

Why does filestreaming create 2 files? According to the code below, first an empty file is created. Then it is given an UNC path to get this empty file and write to it. Is there somehow two filehandles?

**Additional info**

The customer is using SQL Server 2012 and has two instances on it. One for production and one for test.

```
private long SaveToFileTable(string fileContent)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(m_constr))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlTransaction trn = con.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            {
                StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
                sql.AppendLine("insert into Company.FileTable (FileData)");
                sql.AppendLine("output inserted.FileIdentification, inserted.FileData.PathName() as Path, GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() As TransactionContext");
                sql.AppendLine("values(0x)"); //Empty binary value

                byte[] fileData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContent);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(),con, trn);

                string path = null;
                long fileId = 0;
                byte[] context = null;

                // cmd is an INSERT command that uses the OUTPUT clause
                // Thus we use the ExecuteReader to get the
                // result set from the output columns
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    fileId = rdr.GetInt64(0);
                    path = rdr.GetString(1);
                    context = rdr.GetSqlBytes(2).Buffer;
                }

                using (SqlFileStream sfs = new SqlFileStream(path, context, FileAccess.Write, FileOptions.SequentialScan, 0))
                {
                    sfs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                    //file.InputStream.CopyTo(sfs);
                }
                trn.Commit();

                return fileId;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note, the ["OUTPUT clause will return rows to the client even if the statement encounters errors and is rolled back."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) I don't see a rollback, but I could imagine a failed insert that still returns a fileId. The sfs.Write should be in a try/catch. They have a test database; can you do any debugging there?

Comment: Have you found the cause for this issue ? Please update us.

Comment: Same here on SQL2014 but not sure it's an issue as we don't try to read files from the file system.